# Text in table not staying left aligned when I use the set length command

Tags: tables, tabularx

Having a problem with the following table:

```
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    Convenient Amount: &  Coins Given \\
    \emph{Up to nearest 10\cents}& Back:\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Now, the text should be ***left aligned***, hence the l | l , but I also need to keep space on the right for the student to write the answer. So, I need the space on the right, but none on left. How do I fix this?[image]

Comment: What is driving you to set `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt}`? (The default value of this parameter, which governs the amount of whitespace padding on the cells' left- and right-hand edges, is `6pt` in many document classes.) The text *is* actually left-aligned. However, that's hard to discern because of the grotesquely bloated amount of whitespace padding that's generated because of `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{50pt}`.

Comment: Okay, fair. Then how do I put a grotesquely bloated amount of whitespace on the right side, but not the left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding an inordinate amount of whitespace padding along both edges of each column, you may want to set the columns' widths *ex ante* to suitably large values, along the lines of the following test document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for \extrarowheight length parameter
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a slightly more open "look"
\begin{tabular}{|p{6cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
    Convenient amount: \newline (\emph{up to nearest 10 cents}) &  
    Coins given \newline back:\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a fixed width column with blank entry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l w{l}{30pt}|l w{l}{30pt}|}
\hline
Convenient amount:               && Coins given & \\
\emph{Up to nearest 10\textcent} && Back: & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]